# Debian testing wget segfaulting

Tags: debian, wget, backports

Getting an issue where wget is failing with a segfault pretty reliably while trying to run `smxi`. Example:

```
$ wget -O - https://smxi.org/sm/sm-versions   
--2018-01-02 02:24:22--  https://smxi.org/sm/sm-versions
Resolving smxi.org (smxi.org)... 216.92.31.53
Connecting to smxi.org (smxi.org)|216.92.31.53|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
[1]    1928 segmentation fault  wget -O - https://smxi.org/sm/sm-versions
```

This appears to be an issue others have had and they were able to get around this by downgrading to a previous version of wget:
https://techpatterns.com/forums/about2621-10.html

**What is the proper way to downgrade `wget` without causing other dependency issues and blowing up other parts of the distribution for Debian?**

I realize that blindly downgrading can really cause some problems so I'm not sure whether I should downgrade somehow OR if I should simply try to rebuild `wget` from scratch...

Or is there an altogether different fix for `wget` in this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably [Debian bug #880542](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=880542) and [`wget` bug #52581](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?52581).

To downgrade, download the appropriate package from [`wget` 1.19.1-5 snapshots](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/wget/1.19.1-5/) (probably the [`amd64` package](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20171024T092932Z/pool/main/w/wget/wget_1.19.1-5_amd64.deb)) and install it. Even though downgrades aren’t officially supported, this is unlikely to break anything (and *extremely* unlikely to cause anything like the issues mentioned in your forum post).

Once you’ve done that, put a hold on the `wget` package to avoid upgrading it:

```
apt-mark hold wget
```

Comment: Thanks, I simply ran `sudo dpkg -i wget_1.19.1-5_amd64.deb && apt-mark hold wget` and that seemed to do the trick.